# web.config for fatfree framework

Tags: php

I want to develop application using Fatfree Framework 3. My development environment is IIS express 7.5 on Windows XP. I can only access / route in the application. I can't access /about route in the example file. I try webroot/about and webroot/index.php/about. Both are not working. I also try web.config file created from .httaccess which is also not working. When I try to any route, I am getting '**No input file specified.**' error. I am getting the same error for non existing routes also.

my web.config file (Generated from .httaccess file using online utility. I am getting same web.config file from all online utilities

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="rule 1g" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*"  />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php"  appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 2g" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*"  />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/-"  />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Anyone please help me to setup Fatfree Framework on IIS.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem using this framework in IIS 7.5 which i resolved using the config below (from https://github.com/finalcut/php_boilerplate ). Replacing your posted web.config with the below should resolve your problem. (you need to have 'URL Rewrite' installed on your server as well)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="fatfree3" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: the user was having an issue with an automatically generated web.config which wasn't working breaking his routing in FF3 - by replacing his config with with this one i posted, it works correctly - which i believe is a suitable answer? (i agree i didnt word it correctly though)

Comment: Thank you, I been searching the internet for an example. This fixed my problem!